# How can I create a triangle website layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, frontend

I am trying to create a website layout similar to the wireframe attached. The dark grey triangles would have background images with text over the top and ideally be responsive.

I have looked at a few options such as transform and css triangles using borders but cant seem to find a solution that works.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: website wireframe]

Comment: the internet is made up of squares :( I think content will only respect the boundaries of a square/rectangle. You can make things look like a triangle but you will have problems making your content obey the bounds of your triangles for any kind responsive layout. You can put squares in triangles though and hard code positions and widths... but responsive will be a lot of media query styles and trial and error on different screen resolutions

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is neither a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective is for others to help you improve your code. What you are asking for will not be trivial for all device sizes

Comment: This is difficult to implement and responsiveness will be hard. The answer you got shows the only reasonable way I could think of, here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/d0wy58ru/

Comment: @charlietfl I am not looking for a code writing service, just someone to point me along the right track but thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: @ChrisG That looks amazing, definitely gives me a great basis to work from. Thank you so much.

Comment: `transform: rotate(-45deg);`?

Comment: Since my answer was down-voted, I felt challenged, so I came up with a solution: https://codepen.io/lokowebdesign/pen/KbPmye

Comment: looks great @LokoWebDesign, thanks for doing this. really appreciated. Clip path was the route I was starting to explore.